# How would I make a heatmap in pygame on a grid

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a grid on pygame and I was wondering how you could make it so that from a point on that grid the colour changes as you get further away from that point for example goes from a dark blue when it is one square away to a light blue when it is ten squares away. I'm really not sure how to do this and any help would be great.

The grid is created using:

```
grid = []
for y in range(grid_size):
    row = []
    for x in range(grid_size):
        row.append([x * (grid_width + grid_margin) + distance_from_left, y * (grid_height + grid_margin) + distance_from_top, white])
    grid.append(row)
```

the grid is drawn using:

```
for row in grid:
        for x, y, colour in row:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, (x, y, grid_width, grid_height))
```

I also have a function that works out all the childnodes of each node on the grid (all the nodes surrounding it (up, down, sides and diagonally) and I feel that might be useful in working out the distance from the selected node.

Comment: You've to provide more code. How do you draw the grid?

Comment: You can do this with linear interpolation, either write your own or find a function in pygame that will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A color consists of the 3 color channels (reg, green, blue). See [RGB color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model). In this context a color is nothing else than a tuple of 3 vales in range [0, 255].

A dark blue color is e.g. (0, 0, 63) and a light blue color is (127, 191, 255).

You've to interpolate between those 2 values. Calculate a factor in the range [0.0, 1.0], which represents the tint of the color. Use the factor to interpolate the color channels:

e.g `f` is a factor in [0.0, 1.0]

```py
blue = 63 + 192 * f # interpolate between 63 and 255 dependent of f
```

The distance to a between 2 point can be calculated by [`pygame.math.Vector2.
distance_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to):

e.g.

```py
pos = (x, y)
gx = (x + 0.5) * grid_size
gy = (y + 0.5) * grid_size
distance = pygame.math.Vector2(pos).distance_to((gx, gy))
```

e.g. Set a light blue color near the position `pos` and a dark blue color far away from the position:

```py
pos = # (x, y) position

grid = []
for y in range(grid_size):
    row = []
    for x in range(grid_size):

        gx = x * (grid_width + grid_margin) + distance_from_left
        gy = y * (grid_height + grid_margin) + distance_from_top
        distance = pygame.math.Vector2(pos).distance_to((gx + grid_width/2, gy + grid_height/2))
        maxLen = grid_size * (grid_height + grid_margin)

        f = max(0, 1 - distance / maxLen)
        color = (127 * f, 191 * f, 63 + 192 * f)

        row.append([gx, gy, color])
    grid.append(row)
```

[image]

---

The above solution assumes that `pos` is a window coordinate in pixel unit.

If `pos` is a "grid" coordinate, this means `pos` identifies a position in the grid, then the solution is even simpler:

```py
pos = # (x, y) position

grid = []
for y in range(grid_size):
    row = []
    for x in range(grid_size):

        distance = pygame.math.Vector2(pos).distance_to((x, y))

        f = max(0, 1 - distance / grid_size)
        color = (127 * f, 191 * f, 63 + 192 * f)

        gx = x * (grid_width + grid_margin) + distance_from_left
        gy = y * (grid_height + grid_margin) + distance_from_top
        row.append([gx, gy, color])

    grid.append(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help again Rabbid76

Comment: I cant seem to change where the colour change starts from - it always begins in the top left no matter what x and y values i put in

Comment: @JJH562 `pos` has to be a window coordinate (pixel). If you want to us grid coordinates, then it has to be `distance = pygame.math.Vector2(pos).distance_to(x, y)` `f = max(0, 1 - distance / grid_size)`

Comment: Thanks again, great help as usual :)